# How can I sync the value of Meteor's userId to the client?

Tags: meteor

I'm not currently able to use all of Meteor's accounts functionality for compatibility reasons. My system is quite simple, though, I expose an "authenticate" method on the server that performs the necessary authentication work and then, if successful, sets the value of `Meteor.userId()` via `this.setUserId`. The only problem is that when I call `this.setUserId` on the server, it doesn't seem to propagate back to the client. `Meter.userId()` continues to return null on the client, but returns the correct value on the server. Since `this.setUserId` is a server-only function, I'm at a loss as to how I can set the correct user ID on the client after the "authenticate" method returns. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that the Meteor documentation lists "this.setUserId()" as Server-only, it does *currently* work on the client too, so that's how I ended up solving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do more than just set the `userId` in order to authenticate a user. Check out these examples for how to do custom authentication:

- https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous (creates a user for each browser session)
- https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-accounts-testing (creates users without passwords)

The second one is my example. I would strongly suggest building off the functionality provided by the base `accounts` package instead of rolling all your own operations.

**EDIT**: Based on the OP's response, one might be interested in doing a different kind of operation that is not about authenticating; see the following:

> https://dweldon.silvrback.com/impersonating-a-user

Comment: My Meteor app is part of a larger application that already has its own perfectly good authentication system, so I actually do just want to set the user ID on the client. I accept that "this is not possible" might be the correct answer here, however.

Comment: It should definitely be possible - all the existing meteor accounts systems login through things such as Google, GitHub, Facebook, etc. Any of them should be a good example of how to use your other app to log in to Meteor.

Comment: @DerekThurn see the link I added to the post.